# How to pack(condensate) the bytes of a string using or and sll?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, qtspim

I'm writing a program that reads 4 hexadecimals digits, that represent an unsigned integer number, then it condensates those digits in $t1 and finally it calculates and displays the decimal number.

I have completely grasped the solution in theory,but I have trouble using mips as this is my first program. Currently, I have trouble storing the bytes of the string. Here's my code thus far:

```
.data 
msg1:   .asciiz "Enter the hexadecimal :    "
newline:   .asciiz  "\n"
.text

main:
#Print string msg1
li $v0 ,4   # print_string syscall code = 4
la $a0,msg1 #load the adress of msg
syscall

# Get input A from user and save
li  $v0,8       # read_string syscall code = 8
syscall 
move    $t0,$v0     # syscall results returned in $v0

li $v0,10
syscall
```

I know that I'll use lb Rdest, address at some point. But,won't I have to read each digit of the string one by one if that's the case?

Comment: Yes, you will need to read each digit one by one. At each step, shift the partial result left by 4 bits, and fill in the low 4 bits as appropriate for the new digit.

Comment: Thanks @Jester . Could you tell me how to do this? Could I use a character accessing function such as this: 
la $t0, string
lb $a0, ($t0)
li $v0, 11
syscall

Comment: You don't need to print it (which is what syscall #11 does) you can stop at the `lb`. You will probably want a loop.

Comment: @Jester So, loop: beqz $t1,4 
                   la $t0,string
                   lb $a0,($t0)
                    j loop  
? Or something like that? I would really appreciate giving me the code,because while I can grasp the solution in pseudo code I have trouble with mips commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.data
   msg1:   .asciiz "Enter the hexadecimal :    "
   buffer: .space 10
.text

main:
    #Print string msg1
    li $v0 ,4   # print_string syscall code = 4
    la $a0,msg1 #load the adress of msg
    syscall

    # Get input A from user and save
    la $a0, buffer  # address
    li $a1, 10      # length
    li  $v0,8       # read_string syscall code = 8
    syscall

    li $t0, 0                # result
loop:
    lb $t1, ($a0)            # fetch char
    beq $t1, $0, done        # zero terminator?
    addiu $t1, $t1, -10      # line feed?
    beq $t1, $0, done
    addiu $t1, $t1, -38      # convert digit
    sltiu $t2, $t1, 10       # was it a digit?
    bne $t2, $0, append      # yes
    # add validation and upper case here as needed
    addiu $t1, $t1, -39      # convert lower case letter
append:
    sll $t0, $t0, 4          # make room
    or $t0, $t0, $t1         # append new digit
    addiu $a0, $a0, 1        # next char
    j loop

done:
    move $a0, $t0            # print result
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    li $v0,10
    syscall
```